# Non linear population model analysis

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I started watching a course on ODE, In the course lecture first video, the teacher gave some motivations, this example of Non-Linear population model is first among them, the equation is given by $$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay-by^2  (a,b>0)$$

$t_0$ is the intial time and let $y(t_0)=t_0$

and got the solution as $$\frac{1}{a}\ln\Big|\frac{y(a-by_0)}{y_0(a-by)}\Big|=t-t_0 $$ and found out the equilibrium points as $y=0$ and $y=\frac{a}{b}$

And then he gave the solution analysis as exercise, I proceeded and did as follows:

##### Case I: $0<y_0<\frac{a}{b}$

$$\Bigg|\frac{y(a-by_0)}{y_0(a-by)}\Bigg|=e^{a(t-t_0)}$$
from this we note that $y \neq 0$
$$\implies \frac{1}{|\frac{a}{y}-b|}=\frac{y_0 e^{a(t-t_0)}}{a-by_0}$$
$$\implies {\Big|\frac{a}{y}-b\Big|}=\frac{a-by_0}{y_0 e^{a(t-t_0)}}$$
since  RHS is a continuous function and RHS$>0$ and RHS $\neq 0$, LHS$>0$ for all values of y, or LHS<0 for all values of y

Since $\frac{a}{y_0}-b >0$ $$\frac{a}{y}-b >0 ,\forall y$$ $$\implies y<\frac{a}{b}$$ and  $$\frac{a}{y}=\frac{(a-by_0) (e^{-a(t-t_0)})+by_0}{y_0}$$
$$y=\frac{ay_0}{(a-by_0) (e^{-a(t-t_0)})+by_0}$$

Since RHS$>0$, $y>0$ and hence $0<y<\frac{a}{b}$

##### Case II: $y_0>\frac{a}{b}$

$$\Bigg|\frac{y(by_0-a)}{y_0(by-a)}\Bigg|=e^{a(t-t_0)}$$
from this we note that $y \neq 0$
$$\implies \frac{1}{|\frac{a}{y}-b|}=\frac{y_0 e^{a(t-t_0)}}{by_0-a}$$
$$\implies {\Big|\frac{a}{y}-b\Big|}=\frac{by_0-a}{y_0 e^{a(t-t_0)}}$$
since  RHS is a continuous function and RHS$>0$ and RHS$\neq 0$, LHS$>0$ for all values of y, or LHS<0 for all values of y

Since $\frac{a}{y_0}-b <0$ $$\frac{a}{y}-b <0 ,\forall y$$ $$\implies y >\frac{a}{b}$$ and  $$b-\frac{a}{y}=\frac{(by_0-a) (e^{-a(t-t_0)})}{y_0}$$
$$\frac{a}{y}=\frac{by_0-(by_0-a) (e^{-a(t-t_0)})}{y_0}$$
$$y=\frac{ay_0}{(a-by_0) (e^{-a(t-t_0)})+by_0}$$

in conclusion $y>\frac{a}{b}$.

Is this things done and observed in both the cases correct and neat? If not where is the mistake and how to proceed and how to make it much neater